# Unable to submit form in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, httppostedfile

I have the following code which is doing a javscript post using an XmlHttpRequest:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var postedFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
var formElement = document.getElementById("formID");
var form = new FormData(formElement);

form.append('postedFile', postedFile);
request.open("POST", "/Admin/SaveQuestion/", true);
request.send(form);
```

This code is working in Chrome, Firefox, IE10, IE11 but I cannot seem to get it to work on IE9. Would this have something to do with the posted file or does my issue lie with the XmlHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormData is not supported in IE9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thanks Wilmer least I now know where the problem lies, have you had to do workarounds of similar nature for IE9?

Comment: I had but I ended up using a plugin like plupload. I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) however which doesn't use plugins maybe that helps.